# What are relative integers

Tags: stochastic-processes, integers

I'm reading a book on **stochastic processes** and I do not know what are **relative integers**.

[image]

Comment: I have never heard the term "relative integers" in my life.  It does seem to make the chapter more scary and intimidating.  Perhaps the book defines it at some earlier chapter?

Comment: @Michael It does not. The snippet given is the very first occurrence of this notion.

Comment: Bob Gallager has a nice book on Discrete Stochastic Processes (with that name); Sheldon Ross has another nice book on Stochastic Processes.

Comment: I *suspect* that you can replace "relative" with "associated," meaning the integers *associated* with a given event.  Perhaps.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Right. At the very same page, what does the acronym $$GI/GI$$ stand for ?

Comment: @user852508:  You're new here, so you don't know.  But it is very bad etiquette to ask a question, get an answer, and then say (in effect)... "oh... but here's *another* question I want you to answer for me."  Please don't do that.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : What is meant by "the integers associated with a given event"?

Answer (score 2):

This terminology comes from French, where the "entiers relatifs" simply denote the Z set. You are dealing with a French book (as indicated by the names of the authors, François Baccelli and Pierre Brémaud), which has not been translated very well to English.